# I need an XMPP library for PHP

Tags: php, xmpp

And I can't use composer (the server is behind a firewall, and PHP-download.com does not work)

In particular, I need to export the user list with their groups

I have tried https://code.google.com/archive/p/xmpphp/ but it is not compatible with PHP 7

Answer (score 1):

So you can't use composer on the server OK but why you don't use composer on your machine load the dependencies and upload the vendor folder. Then you have all you need.

Composer download all dependencies to the `vendor` folder and generate some autoloading files. When you upload the hole project it should work.

Comment: I'd have to also install a PHP server

Answer (score 0):

```
$server   = "SERVER NAME HERE";
$username = "USER NAME HERE";
$password = "PASSWORD HERE";
$resource = "globe";
$streamid = "";

function vardump($data, $title = false){
    if($title){
        echo '<H2>' . $title . '</H2>';
    }
    echo '<PRE>';
    var_dump($data);
    echo '</PRE>';
}

function open_connection($server) {
    $connection = fsockopen($server, 5222, $errno, $errstr);
    if (!$connection) {
        print "$errstr ($errno)<br>";
        return false;
    }
    return $connection;
}

function send_xml($connection, $xml) {
    fwrite($connection, $xml);
}

function textcontains($text, $searchfor, $or = false){
    return stripos($text, $searchfor) !== false;
}

function send_recv_xml($connection, $xml, $size = 4096) {
    send_xml($connection, $xml);
    $data = recv_xml($connection, $size);
    $data["sent_xml"] = $xml;
    $data["sent_html"] = htmlspecialchars($xml);
    return $data;
}

function fread_untildone($connection, $size = 4096){
    $content = '';
    if($size < 0){
        while(!textcontains($content, '</iq>')){
            $content .= fread($connection, abs($size));
        }
    } else {
        $content = fread($connection, $size);
    }
    /*while(!feof($connection)){//did not work
        $content .= fread($connection, $size);
    }*/
    return $content;
}

function recv_xml($connection, $size = 4096) {
    $xml = fread_untildone($connection, $size);
    if ($xml === "") {
         return null;
    }
    // parses xml
    $xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
    xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $xml, $val, $index);
    xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
    $RET = array($val, $index);
    $RET["originaldata"] = $xml;
    $RET["specialdata"] = htmlspecialchars($xml);
    $RET["time"] = time();
    return $RET;
}

function find_xmpp($connection, $tag, $value=null, &$ret=null) {
    static $val = null, $index = null;
    do {
        if ($val === null && $index === null) {
            list($val, $index) = recv_xml($connection);
            if ($val === null || $index === null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        foreach ($index as $tag_key => $tag_array) {
            if ($tag_key === $tag) {
                if ($value === null) {
                    if (isset($val[$tag_array[0]]['value'])) {
                        $ret = $val[$tag_array[0]]['value'];
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                foreach ($tag_array as $i => $pos) {
                    if ($val[$pos]['tag'] === $tag && isset($val[$pos]['value']) &&
                        $val[$pos]['value'] === $value) {
                            $ret = $val[$pos]['value'];
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $val = $index = null;
    } while (!feof($connection));

    return false;
}

function xmpp_connect($server, $username, $password, $resource = "globe") {
    global $streamid;
    $connection = open_connection($server);
    if (!$connection) {
        return false;
    }
    send_xml($connection, '<stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0" xmlns="jabber:client" to="' . $server . '" xml:lang="en" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">');
    $data = recv_xml($connection);
    $streamid = $data[0][0]["attributes"]["ID"];
    //vardump($streamid, "stream id:");

    send_xml($connection, '<iq type="get" to="' . $server . '" id="auth1"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:auth"><username>' . $username . '</username></query></iq>');
    $data = recv_xml($connection);

    $XML = '<iq type="set" id="auth2"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:auth">';
    $fields = [];
    foreach($data[1] as $KEY => $VALUE){
        $KEY = strtolower($KEY);
        switch($KEY){
            case "username":    $VALUE = $username; break;
            case "password":    $VALUE = $password; break;
            case "digest":      $VALUE = strtolower(sha1($streamid . $password)); break;
            case "resource":    $VALUE = $resource; break;
            default: $VALUE = "";
        }
        $fields[ $KEY ] = $VALUE;
        if($VALUE){
            $XML .= '<' . $KEY . '>' . $VALUE . '</' . $KEY . '>';
        }
    }
    $XML .= '</query></iq>';
    //vardump($fields, "auth");

    $data = send_recv_xml($connection, $XML);
    //vardump($data, 'login');

    return $connection;
}

function xmpp_enum_users($connection, $server, $username, $resource = "globe"){
    //$XML = '<iq from="' . $username . '@' . $server . '/' . $resource . '" id="get-registered-users-list-1" to="' . $server . '" type="set" xml:lang="en">';
    //$XML .= '<command xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/commands" action="execute" node="http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#get-registered-users-list"/></iq>';

    /*$XML = '<iq from="' . $username . '" type="result" to="' . $username . '@' . $server . '/' .  $resource . '" id="123">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items">
        <item jid="conference.localhost" />
        <item jid="pubsub.localhost" />
        <item jid="riot.localhost" />
        <item jid="vjud.localhost" />
        <item node="announce" name="Announcements" jid="localhost" />
        <item node="config" name="Configuration" jid="localhost" />
        <item node="user" name="User Management" jid="localhost" />
        <item node="online users" name="Online Users" jid="localhost" />
        <item node="all users" name="All Users" jid="localhost" />
        <item node="outgoing s2s" name="Outgoing s2s Connections" jid="localhost" />
        <item node="running nodes" name="Running Nodes" jid="localhost" />
        <item node="stopped nodes" name="Stopped Nodes" jid="localhost" />
    </query></iq>';*/
    global $streamid;
    $XML = '<iq from="' . $username . '@' . $server . '/' .  $resource . '" id="' . $streamid . '" type="get"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"/></iq>';
    return send_recv_xml($connection, $XML, -4096);
}

function xmpp_disconnect($connection){
    fclose($connection);
}


$connection = xmpp_connect($server, $username, $password, $resource);
$data = xmpp_enum_users($connection, $server, $username, $resource);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data["originaldata"]);
$users = [];
foreach($xml->query->item as $user){
    $username = $user->attributes()->name;
    $group = $user->group[0];
    $users[$username] = $group;
}

vardump($users, "users");
echo '<HR>' . json_encode($users);
echo '<HR>';
foreach($users as $username => $group){
    echo $username . '=' . $group . '<BR>';
}

xmpp_disconnect($connection);
```

This is the start of an XMPP client. It took a while to find the base code to connect, and I noticed other people asking for this but not getting it.